# write COMMENT tag to WAV and M4A

Tags: android, metadata, wav, m4a, riff

I have an audio app and I need to read and write the COMMENT tag of WAV and M4A files. This is all I need. I had struggled for hours without success.

The closest I arrived is using `com.github.goxr3plus:jaudiotagger:2.2.7`. I had success with WAV written with `AudioRecord` but [exception with M4A written with `MediaRecorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72154696/mediarecorder-produces-jaudiotagger-cannotreadexception).

My question is: How to write the COMMENT tag on files with AudioRecord? I know how to write a WAV file using AudioRecord, including its headers, but I had failed to find a CLEAR specification, like [this one](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat) for the headers.

And yet, in any case, I do not know how to add the COMMENT header for M4A files, with or without external libraries. Clues?

Answer (score 0):

After surfing the web a lot I found the solution [here](https://www.robotplanet.dk/audio/wav_meta_data/), where the crucial information is *"where '....' represents 4 bytes that show the length of each 'chunk'"*. So I did the following method that builds the ICMT chunk for me:

```
byte[] getCMT(String cmt) {
    byte[] cmtBytes = cmt.getBytes();
    int l = cmtBytes.length+12;
    byte[] result = new byte[l+8];
    byte[] list = new byte[]{'L', 'I', 'S', 'T',
            (byte) (l & 0xff),(byte) ((l >> 8) & 0xff),(byte) ((l >> 16) & 0xff),(byte) ((l >> 24) & 0xff)};
    l=l-12;
    byte[] info = new byte[]{'I','N','F','O','I','C','M','T',
            (byte) (l & 0xff),(byte) ((l >> 8) & 0xff),(byte) ((l >> 16) & 0xff),(byte) ((l >> 24) & 0xff)};

    System.arraycopy(list, 0, result, 0, list.length);
    System.arraycopy(info, 0, result, list.length, info.length);
    System.arraycopy(cmtBytes, 0, result, list.length+info.length, cmtBytes.length);
    return result;
}
```

Now it is easy:

```
for (byte datum : getCMT(MyTextComment))
      outStream.write(datum);
```

The only thing to be careful is to choose the string `MyTextComment` with even length.

Sorry if this is well known, adding it for reference since it took me waaaaay too much time.

Comment: None of this is [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3): [WAV/RIFF has its `INFO` chunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format#Use_of_the_INFO_chunk), and [MP4/QTFF has its `meta` atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format#Relation_to_MP4). By far not every metadata is ID3, not even for audio only file formats.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the edition.